# Visual Basic convert string to audio (WAV) file and play

Tags: vb.net, winforms, basic

I'm using a VB win form and need to play a wav from string but I don't know how to do it.

```
Dim URl As String ="http://localhost/main.php?command=readdata"
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URl)
request.Proxy = Nothing
request.UserAgent = "Test"
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream

Dim Reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
Dim data As String = Reader.ReadToEnd
Reader.Close()

Dim AudioData As String = Hex2String(data)

'here i wont play and save this data
```

Comment: Don't use the `StreamReader` to read the `responseStream` as a string.  It's not a string.  It's binary data, so read it as such.  Just write the stream of bytes to a binary file.

Comment: can u show me example ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to read the data as a string, since it's not a string.  WAV data is binary data.  It's meaningless as a string, and if you encode it as a string, you may lose some data in the process.  So, if you aren't converting it to a string, you don't need the `StreamReader` at all.  Just create a new file as a stream, and then copy all the bytes from the one stream to the other:

```
Dim url As String ="http://localhost/main.php?command=readdata"
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
request.Proxy = Nothing
request.UserAgent = "Test"
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Using fileStream As New New FileStream("MyFile.wav", FileMode.CreateNew)
        responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream)
    End Using
End Using
```